# При конвертации знак « меняется на?

Tags: php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$story="«весна»";
$story=mb_convert_encoding($story, "KOI8-R", "UTF-8");
$story=mb_convert_encoding($story, "UTF-8", "KOI8-R");
echo  $story;                               
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно в KOI8-R нет кавычек-елочек. 
Поэтому он и не сможет конвертировать.